# Is there a tool which analyses which functions call which functions for C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, static-code-analysis

For a large porting from VB6 to C# job I wrote a tool which uses a murder of regular expressions to analyse a VB6 code base and extract the dependencies of all the functions in all the forms, bas files and classes.

It allowed us to chop out blocks of code for the developers, generate graphs and extract all the SQL.

I could really use something that does the same thing for C# and although it would be **a lot** easier for C#, I don't have the time or budget to write it.

We are limited to VS2008

Does anything like this already exist?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think NDepend has this. If not, writing it yourself should be pretty straight forward using Roslyn or NRefactory.

Comment: I think [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) does that, but it's a few hundred dollars.

Comment: I would try to use Roslyn for that.

Comment: @Jodrell Which happens to be a built-in function of VS since I can remember.

Comment: @GrantThomas, I was suspicious of that, Visual Studio does it for me when I click "Find Usages".

Comment: We're limited to VS2008, in which all it appears to be is a short cut to Find All. But I'll start going through all those other things, ta.

Comment: Is anyone else curious at all to see "a _murder_ of regular expressions"?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair It's simultaneously one of my proudest and most useful achievements and the the worst example of One Big CS file hack and slash projects which contains about 30-40 regexes. Such as: `(?<!\\)\((\\\(|\\\)|[^\(\)]|(?<!\\)\(.*(?<!\\)\))*(?<!\\)\))?\.)*`. The real killer with chopping up VB6 is no line end char like `;`, block markers like `{` and `}` and being allowed to call "Subs" 8X with no parameter statement. May that language rest in pieces.

Comment: @alexn Looks like NDepends meets my needs, fill in an answer and I'll tick it.

Comment: @RoboJ1M Perfect. Done.

Comment: @RoboJ1M Thanks for posting that. It will serve as a reminder _to not ever try doing that._ :) I am both impressed, and horrified!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure but I think [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) has this. If not, writing it yourself should be pretty straight forward using Roslyn or NRefactory

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look on [project Roslyn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx), you'll find example which will show you about 70% of what you seem to try to achive.

Walkthrough: [Getting Started with Semantic Analysis – C#](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=263973)

Comment: Unfortunately we are limited to VS2008, but I'll make a note of that and continue to dream of modern development tools... :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are doing some kind of "refactoring". I found ReSharper is most useful in this case http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

Comment: Sort of, in the ball park. I've got several developers all bashing away and I want to analyse the design they've come up with, see what functions call what functions and identify mistakes